# Issue with using awk to extract words after/before a specific word

Tags: awk

I have a file which has several sections with a header like this

```
$ head -n 5 test.txt
[44610] gmx@127.0.0.1
  f1(cu_atomdata, NBParamGpu, Nbnxm::gpu_plist, bool), Block Size 64, Grid Size 3599, Device 0, 99 invocations
    Section: Command line profiler metrics
    Metric Name                                                                                  Metric Unit Minimum      Maximum      Average
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------ ------------ ------------
```

I would like to use the following `awk` command to get the number after `Grid Size` and the number before `invocations`. However, the following command returns nothing.

```
$ awk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "Grid Size") print $(I+1)}' test.txt
$ 
$ awk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "invocations") print $(I-1)}' test.txt
$
```

Any idea to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk` that loops through each field and extract your numbers based on field values:

```sh
awk '{
for (i=3;i<NF;i++)
   if ($(i-2) == "Grid" && $(i-1) == "Size")
      print "gridSize:", $i+0
   else if ($(i+1) == "invocations")
      print "invocations:", $i+0
}' file

gridSize: 3599
invocations: 99
```

*Alternatively*, you may try this `gnu grep` with PCRE regex:

```sh
grep -oP 'Grid Size\h+\K\d+|\d+(?=\h+invocations)' file

3599
99
```

- `\K` - match reset
- `(?=...)` - Lookahead assertion

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk` latest versions try putting array within match itself:

```
awk '
match($0,/Grid Size [0-9]+/, arr1){
  print arr1[3]
  match($0,/[0-9]+ invocations/, arr2)
  print arr2[1]
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

With your shown samples could you please try following(when I tried above it didn't work with 4.1 awk version so adding this one as an alternative here).

```
awk '
match($0,/Grid Size [0-9]+/){
  num=split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr1," ")
  print arr1[num]
  match($0,/[0-9]+ invocations/)
  split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr2," ")
  print arr2[1]
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

make it even simpler :

```
{mawk/mawk2/gawk} 'BEGIN { 

          FS = "(^.+Grid Size[ ]+|" \      # before
                 "[,][^,]+[,][ ]+|"  \     # in-between
                 "[ ]+invocations.*$)";    # after

   } NF == 4 { print "grid size \043 : " $2 ", invocations \043 : " $3 }'
```

This regex gobbles everything before, in between, and after it. Because the regex touches the 2 walls at the ends, fields $1 and $4 will also be created, but as empty ones, hence the NF==4 check.

The octal code `\043` is the hash symbol `#` - just my own personal preference of not having comment delimiter inside my strings is its original form.

Answer (score 0):

a `gawk` approach with `gensub`:

```
$ gawk '/Grid Size/{
    s=gensub(/.*Grid\sSize\s([[:digit:]]+).*,\s([[:digit:]]+) invocations/, "gridSize: \\1\ninvocations: \\2","G"); print s
  }' myFile
gridSize: 3599
invocations: 99
```